# What are exactly the superconducting domes?

Tags: condensed-matter, terminology, definition, superconductivity, graphene

Do domes here mean the shape of some superconducting state?
Or does it have a different meaning here?

Answer (score 2):

It refers to the shape of the superconducting region in the temperature/hole-concentration  phase diagram.  It's a kind on bump up from the $T=0$ line with a maximum at "optimal doping".